# Marshmallow: mapping string db column to dict field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have the following database table in SQL server:

```
COLUMN_NAME              ORDINAL_POSITION DATA_TYPE       
----------------------------------------------------
id                       1 varchar
collection_id            2 varchar
created_at               3 datetimeoffset  
mimetype                 4 varchar
size                     5 int
file_hash                6 varchar
storageKey               7 varchar
extra_data               8 varchar
```

this is mapped to a Marshmallow Schema in flask app like so:

```
class ImageDisplaySchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str()
    created_at = fields.Str()
    collection_id = fields.Str()
    mimetype = fields.Str()
    size = fields.Int()
    extra_data = fields.Dict()
```

I'm struggling to find the right `pre_dump`/`pre_load` helpers to serialize/deserialize the `extra_data` column which is saved in the database as a json string. I've tried a few variations but always end up with a serialization exception.  Here's my current version of the `pre_dump` helper:

```
    @pre_dump
    def serialize_extra_data(self, data, many):
        """This will alter the data passed to ``dump()`` before Marshmallow
        attempts serialization.
        """
        print(type(data), type(data.extra_data), data.extra_data)
        extra_data = data.extra_data
        data.extra_data = json.loads(extra_data)
        return data
```

But this attempts to push a dictionary rather than a string into the DB:

```
cartridgeocr-annotations-1           |   File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1976, in pymssql._mssql._quote_or_flatten
cartridgeocr-annotations-1           | ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
```

On the other hand if I change the `loads` to a `dumps`, some other serialization point complains that I don't have a dictionary in the field:

```
cartridgeocr-annotations-1           | ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

The latter exception occurs when the flask app attempts to dump the object in a query response:

```
 return schemas.ImageDisplaySchema().dump(image_in_db), 201
```

I'm looking for a working example of how to seamlessly convert the db string to a dictionary and back via Marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

When using SQLAlchemy, I usually return a model object as an output of the load of the marshmallow schema by using `post_load`. So the code could like this :

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass

from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pre_dump, post_load


@dataclass
class DbModel:
    id: str
    collection_id: str
    created_at: datetime
    mimetype: str
    size: int
    file_hash: str
    storage_key: str
    extra_data: str


class ImageDisplaySchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str()
    created_at = fields.Str()
    collection_id = fields.Str()
    mimetype = fields.Str()
    size = fields.Int()
    extra_data = fields.Dict()

    @pre_dump
    def serialize_extra_data(self, data, many):
        """This will alter the data passed to ``dump()`` before Marshmallow
        attempts serialization.
        """
        print(type(data), type(data.extra_data), data.extra_data)
        extra_data = data.extra_data
        data.extra_data = json.loads(extra_data)
        return data
    
    @post_load
    def deserialize_to_model(self, data, **kwargs):
        # dumps : dict => str
        extra_data = json.dumps(data.pop("extra_data"))
        return DbModel(
            **data,
            extra_data=extra_data,
            file_hash=None,
            storage_key=None
        )


db = DbModel("id", "collection_id", datetime.now(), "mimetype", 1, "hash", "storage", '{"extra": "data", "key": 1}')

# dump : object => dict
dumped = ImageDisplaySchema().dump(db)
assert isinstance(dumped["extra_data"], dict)

# load : dict => object
to_db = ImageDisplaySchema().load(dumped)
assert isinstance(to_db.extra_data, str)
```

Side note :

> On the other hand if I change the loads to a dumps, some other
> serialization point complains that I don't have a dictionary in the
> field

As per the documentation of json stdlib :
**dumps**
Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str using this conversion table. The arguments have the same meaning as in dump().

**loads**
Deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

So doing a `json.dumps` on a `str` doesn't work as the function expects a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Re your side note, the serialization issue isn't in json serialization, it's marshmallow complaining about the presence of a string rather than a dict. json.dumps('foo') has no problem producing a json-serialized string.